# Converting datagridview to data table along with colors

Tags: c#

I have a data gridview which has color for specific cells (color changes from cell to cell).I converted that data gridview into data table, but I am not getting colors in my data table. I want data table as same as data gridview along with colors. I tried doing with DataBindingComplete event handler still it is not working. If I try to put colors then the entire column will get same color and I don't want that. Can you help me out please?

```
// Converting dataGridView1 into datatable dtSource.
            foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView1.Rows)
            {
                DataRow drNewRow = dtSource.NewRow();
                foreach (DataColumn col in dtSource.Columns)
                {
                     drNewRow[col.Columns] = row.Cells[col.Columns].Value;
                     dtSource.Rows.Add(drNewRow);
                }
             }
             dataGridView2.AutoSizeRowsMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeRowsMode.AllCells;
            DataGridViewCellStyle style = dataGridView2.ColumnHeadersDefaultCellStyle;
            style.Font = new Font(dataGridView1.Font, FontStyle.Bold);
            dataGridView2.GridColor = Color.Black;
            bindingSource.DataSource = dtSource;
            dataGridView2.DataSource = bindingSource;
```

Comment: can you please let us know what you have done so far in code part.

Comment: DataTable is an object which will hold the data. It has nothing to do with color. So, I'm not sure what you want to achieve. The closest solution could be to have an extra column in DataTable to hold the style element.